# Which AWG for an RGB LED Stripe?

Tags: wire, heat

I've bought a RGBLED stripe with 300 SMD5050 RGBLEDs. These are rated at ~18mA on 5V each, so I have approximately 5.4A on the complete strip. I have to cut down the strip into several parts and have to connect them with short wires of 10-30cm each.

According to the AWG table, I would need to use an AWG14 or AWG13 to be sure, but that seems rather large for the application I have. With a total wire length of approximately 5m, whould it be ok to go for an AWG in the range of 20-24 without having to worry about the wires getting too hot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic rule: 10 A for 1 mm2, so AWG 17-18 should be enough.
AWG 20-24 will give you about +20-30'C.

Comment: do you have a source for me to read upon that topic? Especially about the increase in temperature.

Comment: googled some in english "COPPER WIRE CURRENT CAPACITY"
http://www.cmcorporation.com/conductors/current-carrying-capacity-of-copper-conductors

Comment: well, sometimes the correct search term makes the difference - thanks!